# SINR and Signal power Pr[dBm] calculations in Veins simulations

Tags: omnet++, veins

I need help in the following,
**Question-1:** In veins simulations, how the *SINR* of a signal is calculated and where its implemented in the code?
**Question-2:** In veins simulations, how the *Pr[dBm]* of a signal is calculated and where its implemented in the code? Is it the receiver's antenna where the signal is first received?
**Question-3:** Where in the code i can find the decision making process of accepting or rejecting the signal when the signal is received with a certain power that is below of above some threshold? How can we set the threshold/sensitivity level?

thanks in advance,

Best regards,
/MM

Answer (score 1):

If you think for a moment about how a physical system behaves, you might end up understanding the folders structure of Veins. A signal arrives at an antenna, if it's too weak (less than sensitivity), it's withdrawn *a priori*, otherwise it's going to a decoder and there you might have some errors in proportion to the SINR you got.

1. Statistics are generated in [Mac1609_4.cc](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mac/ieee80211p/Mac1609_4.cc)
2. I'm a bit unsure on this, you'll be able to find yourself after reading this.
3. Decision making? [Decider80211p.cc](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/86c19cef71caccd6b9d25ed4dd7da8395bd1f059/src/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211p.cc#L42) (how cool is that?!)

To look after source files, in Omnet++ you could use Ctrl+left click to find in which files something is defined/declared. I'm still studying myself so please verify this information. Let me know in the comments the answer to number 2.